# Highlighting One of my Line Graphs in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Here is a link to my example [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YMOLJMrc8iWNPdQsmCwm_3j4YEKS-ZXk-28YyklrvP0/edit?usp=sharing)

What I want to do is create one graph with of only the values when the "Number" column has a 1 and with X on the X-Axis, Y on the Y-Axis and have multiple different colored lines on each graph based on the "Other" column. But I would like to be able to control the color of the line when Other = 2.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

Data <- read.csv("Example_Data.csv")
Data <- na.omit(Data)

DF <- data.frame(
     DF1 <- Data[Data$Number == 1,],
     DF2 <- Data[Data$Number == 2,],
     DF3 <- Data[Data$Number == 3,]
)

Plot1 <- ggplot(data = DF1, aes(x = factor(Xaxis)), y = Yaxis, color = Other) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Yaxis, group = Other)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Yaxis)) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y", title =  "Y vs X with Number = 1") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(5)) +
  ylim(-1, 2)
Plot1
```

So all of that plots something like this:
[image: Plot I got]

But none of my lines are colored and I do not know how to control the color of my specific Other = 2 line.

This is obviously made up data and the data I am actually working with has way more than just 3 values in my "Other" column, that is why I want to know how to control the color of just one of those lines. For example I'd like to have all of my colors different shades of the rainbow except for my specific value I'd want to be black.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your data, post the structure of it using `dput(YOURDATA)`  or `dput(head(YOURDATA))` if it's too big to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a vector of colors to be used outside of ggplot2 and then subset your dataset when plotting with ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
colors = rainbow(5)
ggplot(data = subset(df, Number == 1 & Other !=2), aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis, group = Other))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data = subset(df,  Number == 1 & Other ==2),color = colors[3])+
  geom_line(data = subset(df,  Number == 1 & Other ==2),color = colors[3])
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create a column `Color` on your dataframe based on the color pattern you want to obtain:

```r
library(dplyr)
colors = rainbow(5)
df <- df%>% mutate(Color = ifelse(Other ==2, colors[3],"black"))

  Xaxis Yaxis Number Other Color
1     1  1.00      1     1 black
2     2  0.95      1     1 black
3     3  0.80      1     1 black
4     4  0.70      1     1 black
5     5  0.55      1     1 black
6     6  0.40      1     1 black
```

And then, use it in `ggplot2` using `scale_color_identity` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(df, Number == 1), aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis, group = Other, color = Color))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_identity()
```

**EDIT: Setting a color gradient and then modifying a single line**

Based on your comments, we can set a color gradient to your dataframe by doing:

```r
Colors = rainbow(length(unique(df$Other)))
df$Color = Colors[df$Other]

ggplot(subset(df, Number == 1), aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis, group = Other, color = Color))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_identity()
```

You can change `rainbow` to any kind of color gradient you want for your data or create your own palette of color.

[image]

Then, if you want to manipulate the color of a particular group based its value in the column `Other`, you can do:

```r
df <- df%>% mutate(Color = ifelse(Other ==2, "darkorchid",Color))

ggplot(subset(df, Number == 1), aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis, group = Other, color = Color))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

**EDIT 2: Adding a legend**

If you need to add a legend to this plot, you can pass the following argument to `scale_color_identity`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
Colors = rainbow(length(unique(df$Other)))
df$Color = Colors[df$Other]

ggplot(subset(df, Number == 1), aes(x = Xaxis, y = Yaxis, group = Other, color = Color))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", 
                       breaks = c("#FF0000FF","#00FF00FF","#0000FFFF"),
                       labels = c("Other = 1","Other = 2","Other = 3"))
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
structure(list(Xaxis = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L
), Yaxis = c(1, 0.95, 0.8, 0.7, 0.55, 0.4, 0.25, 0.15, 0.08, 
0.02, 0.01, 1.03, 0.98, 0.83, 0.73, 0.58, 0.43, 0.28, 0.18, 0.11, 
0.05, 0.04, 1.06, 1.01, 0.86, 0.76, 0.61, 0.46, 0.31, 0.21, 0.14, 
0.08, 0.07, 0.95, 0.9, 0.75, 0.65, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.1, 0.03, 
-0.03, -0.04, 0.98, 0.93, 0.78, 0.68, 0.53, 0.38, 0.23, 0.13, 
0.06, 0, -0.01, 1.01, 0.96, 0.81, 0.71, 0.56, 0.41, 0.26, 0.16, 
0.09, 0.03, 0.02, 1.5, 1.45, 1.3, 1.2, 1.05, 0.9, 0.75, 0.65, 
0.58, 0.52, 0.51, 1.53, 1.48, 1.33, 1.23, 1.08, 0.93, 0.78, 0.68, 
0.61, 0.55, 0.54, 1.56, 1.51, 1.36, 1.26, 1.11, 0.96, 0.81, 0.71, 
0.64, 0.58, 0.57), Number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Other = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -99L))
```

Comment: Almost! I was hoping the other two lines could be apart of a color scale of sorts.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment. Can you clarify it ? What color should be the other two lines ?

Comment: In my real dataset, (not my example here) I have over 30+ different lines on a graph. So I was hoping not to name every single color for each line on the graph. I was wondering if I could somehow do that automatically. So for example I would have a really dark color (like purple lets say) for the lower numbers and a really light color (like yellow) for the higher numbers. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: But your question was about one line. so, basically all of your lines will have a rainbow color ? you want to be able to control the color gradient based on the value ? Does the color has to be the same on a single line or for a single line, low value will have a color and high value an another one ? The second part of my answer shows you how to define color pattern outside of ggplot2, does it look what you are expecting ?

Comment: Sorry I definitely could have been more clear. So basically I want all of my lines to be on a color gradient based on the value. But then I want to be able to change the color of one value to something completely different. So lets say I have numbers 1 - 30 lines on the same graph. I want them to start on a dark color and end on a light color. But then I want the value of when number = 15 and make that any color I want. Does that make sense?

Comment: The color gradient is defined based on the value of the `Other` column, right ? not based on the Xaxis value ?

Comment: Correct, the color is based off of my "Other" column in my example data above.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly, does it look better now ?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me by the way. I have one more question though. I am trying to add a legend, and they ways I know how are either not working or I'm doing them wrong. How would you add a legend to your graph above?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to add a legend on it. You will have to customize it and be cautious about the definition of `breaks` especially if you decide to manually change one color. Hope it answer your question.